# What are the step to follow with the same user asking the same thing over and over again?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, formulado-de-preguntas

The case of this user https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/2606/bruce

He ask 3 times the same question and ask again in an answer

1- [voiceless vs voiced consonants / consonantes sordas vs sonoras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5177/voiceless-vs-voiced-consonants-consonantes-sordas-vs-sonoras)

2- https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/questions-in-spanish-pronuciation

3- https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-dont-be-fed-up-with-me-for-this-question-i-just-ask-for-the-last-time-ye

and in an answer that was removed he ask again.

I think this something more that a misunderstanding of how the website works.

What are the step that the moderators should take to avoid this kind of things.

I know for example in Stackoverflow when you have certain quantity of question with downvotes or Duplicates you wont be able to ask, or if you are really doing spam you will be banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that he probably doesn't understand how the site works. I have closed and deleted the three duplicate questions (which incidentally were asked by a duplicate user).

For now, I'll leave well enough alone. If the problem persists, the moderators can contact the user to try to help him, or take whatever other action is necessary.